# Extract values from string using substring

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Struggling to write `SUBSTRING` function to extract values from below mentioned string.

`String1 = [The Aggregate Total Incremental Facility Commitments shall not, at any time, exceed [10 million].]`

Output Expected: `String1 = 10 million`

`String2 = a Borrower (or the Parent) may select an Interest Period of [[ 12] or [24]] Months`

Output Expected: `String2 = [[ 12] or [24]] Months`

`String3 = excluding all intra-group items and investments in Subsidiaries of any member of the Group) exceeds [10]% of [ABC]`

Output Expected: `String 3 = [10]%`

Comment: The rule doesnt seem to consistent at all. If  you can create a consistent rule then you have your logic to write.

Comment: So, what it is the logic behind this, you seem to have omitted it (and I can't seem to see any consistency)? What were the attempts you made so far? Do you *have* to use SQL Server? String manipulation is far from it's forté.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
declare @String1 varchar(1000)= '[The Aggregate Total Incremental Facility Commitments shall not, at any time, exceed [10 million].]'
declare @String2 varchar(1000)= 'a Borrower (or the Parent) may select an Interest Period of [[ 12] or [24]] Months'
declare @String3 varchar(1000)= 'excluding all intra-group items and investments in Subsidiaries of any member of the Group) exceeds [10]% of [ABC]'

select substring(@string1, charindex('[', @string1, 2)+1, charindex(']', @string1, 1)-charindex('[', @string1, 2)-1)

select substring(@string2, charindex('[', @string2, 1), 100)

select substring(@string3, charindex('[', @string3, 1), charindex('%', @string3, 1)-charindex('[', @string3, 1)+1)
```

***N.B.***: Answer is very specific to the given strings only.